# Maven install throws errors with missing classes

Tags: java, maven, asterixdb

I was setting up the environment for Asterix DB project in my Mac (Monterey 12.6.5).
I installed the latest Java, and Maven from their respective sources (Java Home was set, and Maven was also set to the extracted bin folder).
When I git pulled the Project and tried to maven install it, the following error threw up.

[image: Error at hyracks-util 0.3.9]

Below is my pom.xml file

```
<!--
 ! Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 ! or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 ! distributed with this work for additional information
 ! regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 ! to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 ! "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 ! with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 !
 !   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 !
 ! Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 ! software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 ! "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 ! KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 ! specific language governing permissions and limitations
 ! under the License.
 !-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>apache-asterixdb-fullstack</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>hyracks-asterix</name>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache</artifactId>
    <version>18</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>

  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
      <comments>A business-friendly OSS license</comments>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <modules>
    <module>hyracks-fullstack</module>
    <module>asterixdb</module>
  </modules>

</project>
```

I reset may entire PC before attempting this. Git was installed using Homebrew but nothing else was installed.

Comment: Please do not use images for text information in Slackoverflow. Makes it more difficult to help, can not be used to search o extract information, and site guidelines say don´t do it.

Comment: You'll need to include the hyracks-util pom.xml in your question, at least.

Comment: You should use the most. recent version of impsort-maven-plugin (1.9.0)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `impsort-maven-plugin` plugin should declare dependencies on `plexus-utils` if use it.

With Maven 3.8.x and older `plexus-utils` was always added to plugin classpath - [MNG-6965](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6965)

You can check if newer version of `impsort-maven-plugin` is available with fixes, if no you can add dependencies to plexus-utils for plugin in your project.

eg:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>plugin.groupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>impsort-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>xxx</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
      <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: The most recent version (1.9.0) already has that dependency correctly added